# Sub0 Presentation Slides

Tags: general

Is there a way to download presentation slides from Sub0 [2020](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCJBPAZIAdQ&list=PLp0_ueXY_enUZk1RuEAU9ly5h0wy5FuLs&index=2) & [2021](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bp41Y_AHym4&list=PLp0_ueXY_enX6S5sogeo7GHD1BXTLj5Xr)?
I would like to use them to present Substrate to my coworkers.

Comment: If you are more specific on the ones you want, i may be able to find and share some of them, but there is no public place where they all currently exist.

Comment: I would love to get access to ["What the Hack is Substrate"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCJBPAZIAdQ&list=PLp0_ueXY_enUZk1RuEAU9ly5h0wy5FuLs&index=2) and ["Anatomy of a Substrate Node"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LlhH1CsNg4&list=PLp0_ueXY_enUZk1RuEAU9ly5h0wy5FuLs&index=3)
If you find them, could you please share them here with links to a cloud drive for other people to use or send them via email: creestl.job@yandex.ru

Comment: I couldn't find "What the heck is substrate" slides, but happy to look for others if you specify more.

Answer (score 1):

You can find "Anatomy of a Substrate Node" here:

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1bOn6nsf60LGUwPnRz3zIac1eTPz4EOuX/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106359707660635712012&rtpof=true&sd=true